# Proxy server in C#

Tags: java, c#, networking, proxy

I am a newbie in network programming in C# and I want to create a proxy server which can be used to restrict users from connecting to internet if they have exceeded the download limit.

My current config is ---- User -> proxy server -> wifi router -> internet.

I searched everywhere and I found that HTTP proxy can be created but it is very hard to create a HTTPS proxy in C#

Even the c# library like Trotinet and mentalis does not support the HTTPS proxy.

But I found that there are many library in JAVA like little proxy that support HTTPS connection.

So, Is it possible to create a fully functional proxy in C#? or should I try switching to JAVA?

One More question. Can I create a simple TCP client read its networkstearm and forward that stream as it is to wifi router without need to read its header or anything, will this method work? Just a guess, sorry for noob question.

Thanks

Comment: In answer to your question on whether you can create a TCP Client and read its stream, yes you can do this, using a class called TcpClient and it's associated method GetStream(). Just create a listener, AcceptClient(), have a separate client connect to the destination and forward everything received in the listening stream to the destination stream.  You'll still need to process at least one header packet, so you know what the destination should be.  Here's a tutorial on TcpListener and TcpClient http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server

Comment: I have done that but the problem I am facing is TCPClient requires a port number. Do wifi routers have a port number? I am searching on google and I am still not able to find what is the port number of my router.

Comment: I think you might misunderstand how networks and TCP in particular work. Your network will take care of routing for you.  You only need to connect to the destination at point described in your diagram as 'internet'.

Comment: I read that tutorial. The problem I am facing is at this point.
`IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3000);`

My router address is 192.168.1.1 and if I give any port number to it i get an error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

Comment: You should inspect the HTTP request and get the Host header from that.

Comment: I agree with Steve Lillis.  If you are attempting to connect to some port on the router's IP address, you have a fundamental misunderstanding of IP-based networking. You should be attempting to connect to the IP address + port of some remote server ... not your router.

Comment: Yes I know wifi routers does not work on the same layer, and they dont have ports, and the method of TCPClient wont work because of that. I was not able to find any good article for HTTPS proxy so I was looking for some workaround for it.

Answer (score 2):

Answer for your first question : YES, you can create full functional HTTPS proxy with C# (similar to Fiddler). No need for changing to Java. Just for testing purpose you can use Fiddler Core. Fiddler core is a complete HTTPS Proxy written in C#. If you have time and knowledge, do reverse engineering by using reflector on fiddler core and get some idea about implementation.

Last commit on Trotinet has a shy implementation of HTTPS pass thru. So unless you dont want to decrypt the https data, Trotinet will be a good choice.

-Kumar